Lightningchartjs performance issue setInterval takes more than 10 seconds when sync axises is on
lightningchartjs version 5.2.1 from @arcion/lcjs
performance issue when trying to setInterval of charts sync axises is on
is there any way to debug the reason why this takes so long?
its pretty difficult to create a demo to reproduce the bug as it is inside a complex project
does anyone faces this kind of issues before and have hints that I can search for ?


This issue was caused by not cleaning up side effect created by synchronizeAxisIntervals in useEffect cleanup handler.

can you also upvote my question ?

How to cleanup side effect of synchronizeAxisIntervals?
